# Memcache Master and slaves

Tags: linux, php, replication, cache, memcached

I'm using memcached-1.4.5-1.el5 & memcache-2.2.6 as php extension and memcached-1.2.8-repcached-2.2.1 for replication.

The above packages are installed on 4 servers. How can I do the following?

Server1 : Memcache Master

Server2,3,4 : Memcache Slave

And can I run memcached-repcached and memcache on the same default port 11211?

Comment: Why you need to set up master->slaves ?

Comment: @mezgani I need it for replication process, Any thing which are written on master server is replicated automatically on slaves servers.

Comment: Hi, I know its a very old question, but are you using repcached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this page](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-memcached-with-repcached-built-in-server-side-replication-on-debian-lenny). It explains how to setup master-master replication. The memcached-repcached add two more options to the official memcached options which are:

```
-x < ip_addr > hostname or IP address of the master replication server
-X < num > TCP port number of the master (default: 11212)
```

It should be easier to setup master-slave replication if you want.

For your question about running memcached and memcached-repcached on the same port. You don't need to run the original memcached daemon and modified memcached-repcached daemon at the same time. If you want to use the replication feature, you don't need to run the original memcached daemon.

As a general rule, it is not allowed to run more than one service (daemon) on any specific port number on the same host.

Comment: **Master** Server IP : **10.10.10.1**

..I put the following config for memcache repcache config ( on **Slave** Servers ) in _/etc/sysconfig/repconfig_ 
`PORT="11211"`
`USER="memcached"`
`MAXCONN="1024"`
`CACHESIZE="256"`
`OPTIONS="-x 10.10.10.1"`

Is it right .? and does i need to put the same config in **master** server with removing of OPTIONS directive .?